# Renewal of Apple Enterprise cert and impact to existing provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, provisioning

I manage the iOS Enterprise distribution for several clients.  We have come to a situation where a distribution certificate is near expiration and are curious as to the ramifications of cert renewal.  The goal is maintain application integrity and not require app reinstallation.  Is there a way to renew the certificate and regenerate the provisioning profiles, without impacting the end user?

If I renew the certificate and regenerate the provisioning profiles, will the end user be required to reinstall the application?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

From the apple enterprise FAQ:

`Distribution provisioning profiles expire 12 months after they’re issued. Two months    before expiration, the iOS device begins displaying notifications about the impending expiration. After the expiration date, the app won’t launch.`

`Before to a provisioning profile expires, use the iOS Development Portal to create a new profile for the app. Create a new app archive (.ipa) with the new provisioning profile, for users who are installing the app for the first time.`

`For users who already have the app, you may want to time your next released version so that it includes the new provisioning profile. If not, you can distribute just the new .mobileprovision file so users won’t have to install the app again. The new provisioning profile will override the one that’s already in the app archive.`

Source: http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/mac/1.1/#app43ad802c